# "Call to a member function store() on null" Laravel how to fix

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5FLb.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5FLb.png%60) "Call to a member function store() on null" Laravel how to fix`

```
 <form action="{{route('add')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit">

</form>`

 function add(Request $request){
    $request->file('image')->store('public');
```

}

Comment: are you using javascript here at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should be like :

```
public function add(Request $request)
 {
     request()->validate([
         'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
     ]);
     $imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
     return back()->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

Comment: they were using `store` which uses the storage disks which also has the filename generated automatically, btw

Comment: The image must be an image.
The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg

Comment: but file 100% image

Comment: Try with another image